# Convert year and month variables to timestamp in Postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I have to variables: year and month, both of type integer.

E.g:

`year` = 2016
`month` = 1

I want to, in my select statement, return a timestamp given those two variables.

I've had a look at the documentation, specifically `to_timestamp` and `to_date`, but all the examples I've come across show a string being converted into a timestamp.

I do not really want to convert my `year` and `month` into a string, such as:

```
to_timestamp(to_char(int,year) + ' ' + to_char(int, month),YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS)
```

So, how can I (if it is possible) convert my `year` and `month` into a timestamp?

Comment: What values do you want for the day?  The hour?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen just the defaults - it's really just the year and month that I am interested in. The day can be the first and the time can be midnight.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Postgres 9.4 or later, you could try using [`make_timestamp()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions-datetime.html):

```
make_timestamp(2016, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0.0)
```

This would create a timestamp for January 1, 2016 at midnight.  We need to specify values for the other components, even if they end up not being relevant to your query/calculation (e.g. you only need the date).

Comment: Perfect. Thank you.

Comment: I had to wait 10 minutes before marking as correct.